# Variable read only

Tags: c#, oop, readonly, access-modifiers

I have a problem with changing a variable from different class. Even tho I used access modifiers (get and set), compiler still sees it as read only, and I cannot change it within another class.

```
private float speed;

public float Speed
{
    get {return speed;}
    set {speed = value;}
}
```

I'm not sure if this matters, but this variable is from my main, abstract class and I use it in other classes. What is happening here, is that I assigned value to this variable in one class (Player.cs) and I'm trying to change it in another class by initializing its object (Physics.cs). They are both inheriting from that main, abstract class.

Comment: Be sure you try changing `Speed` and not `speed`.

Comment: Are you working with the same instance?

Comment: where are you specifying that the property is `readonly` ..?
[Creating Read-Only Properties](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson10)

Comment: `Grant Winney` good point I just re-read it and the wording is misleading the way that the code is written should actually have worked.. I removed my comment perhaps the OP is doing something wrong in code and overwriting it somewhere else in the process sorry about that

Comment: It's like this. For this example only I'm using 3 classes: MainClass.cs, Player.cs, Physics.cs
In MainClass.cs I have variable called "protected float speed" (I'm sorry that I wrote private, it's protected), and with that I have get-set method in it for accessing it.
In Player.cs I set the value of speed for that class only (this.speed = 3f;)
In Physics.cs I want to change the value of speed by doing player.Speed = 4f; 
I have initialized player object

Comment: @Meetz: As you describe it, there is no reason for it not to work. You need to include a (simplified) example of your actual usage with your three classes in your question (click the edit button - don't try and put code in a comment).

Comment: Auto property actually solved it, I still have no idea why.. Anyway, thank you all for your help. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only setting `speed` once, just use a readonly variable and set it in the constructor:

```
public class Physics
{
    private readonly float speed;

    public Physics()
    {
        this.speed = 5;
    }
}
```

You can set a `readonly` variable exactly once.

If you really do need to change `speed` within the lifetime of your object, just use an auto property anyways for simplicity:

```
public float Speed {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access speed from a child class, make sure that its defined as protected (not private) in the base class.  private really is private.  Nothing outside of the class where it is defined can access it.  Protected allows classes that inherit to access it.

(If I understood your question correctly, that is.  I'm confused, though... if you are trying to access the speed variable directly, then why have the public properties?)

Comment: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson10